# How can I import runtime config in Nuxt without using useContext

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to import a public `$config` file without using useContext hook in nuxt composition API.

According to Nuxt3 official document, we are able to import config file without using `useContext` hook. You can read [this](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/usage/runtime-config/#api-routes) document.

Like this:

```
import config from '#config'
```

Just wondering, is that possible in Nuxt2?

nuxt version: 2.14.9

@nuxtjs/composition-api version: ^0.29.0

Comment: `publicRuntimeConfig` is not good enough?

Comment: @kissu how can I import `publicRuntimeConfig` safely? Regular import would be safe enough?

Comment: Safe enough? It's public so yeah, it's safe. All details are available in the linked question.